# Transfer WordPress post to RoR site: is the REST Api the only and/or best solution?

Tags: posts, rest-api

I'm creating a new version of my site without WordPress, using Ruby on Rails.
How can I transfer all my posts and users to this new site ? 
I was thinking of using the REST Api but none of the functions related to the Posts allow to retrieve the whole post (images+text+author): https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/

What would be the best solution ? It should be possible even if my new site is powered by Rails since the pages are always just HTML/CSS/JS and does not include PHP.

Comment: Sorry, if I sound rude, but shouldn´t you have a plan how to move BEFORE you actually move? And what is your page afterwards like? Like WordPress? Then why not stick to it?

Comment: The DB structure should be described somehow. For more info on how to [acquire this info see here](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/3933/385). Please [edit] your question with those details. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the file that wordpress generate at "export". It should contain the basic info you are talking about (although not the user's passwords if you are expecting to get it as well). It is just an xml file which you can parse, you can even look at the code of the wordpress importer for guidance.

Comment: Export `!==` import. Those are two different plugins where one (importer) is currently heavily refactored by Ryan McCue on GitHub and will replace the old one. Just FYI. Also it would be nice to have a bit more than just a route where to go in an answer.

Comment: @kaiser, I don't get the Export !== import. You need somehow to export the data whether it is by sql dump, rest api or the built-in exporter. Then you can do import but never before that. As for the comment about quality, If I got it right the question is about the route ;)